# The 'Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0' provider is not registered on the local machine

Tags: oledb

I spent last two days trying to solve this error

The 'Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0' provider is not registered on the local machine

no luck!!! :(

i am running windows xp sp2

please help me i am ..,..., frustrated!!

thanks

Comment: Are you running a 64 bit version of Windows XP?

Answer (score 1):

Are you running 64 Bit?  Here's the latest drivers which supports it:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/239114

It took MS forever to get 64 Bit drivers for Jet 4.0.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this by going to project properties | Build, and changing Platform Target to x86.

Answer (score 0):

If it's the 32 bit windows, and it worked previously, maybe right click mdac.inf in c:\windows\inf and choose Install to reinstall/repair it. It may ask for your windows cd.

Answer (score 0):

try

regsvr32 /u Msjet40.dll

regsvr32 Msjet40.dll

Answer (score 0):

Yes, one way it can be resolved by making the value of the property `Run64BitRuntime` to be false in project property.

http://wpfgrid.blogspot.com/2013/01/sql-server-2012-ssis-excel-import-fail.html

```
SQL Server 2012 SSIS Excel import fail issue due to OLE Jet driver
```

SSIS project fails to build due to OLE Jet drive 64 bit version and you get the following error:

```
Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0 is not registered
```

Here is what you can do:

Right click on your SSIS project name and choose properties, go to:

```
Configuration Properties -> Debugging tab. (expand Configuration Properties if you do to see Debugging right way).
```

Make the value of the property Run64BitRuntime to be false.