# The 'Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0' provider is not registered on the local machine on server 2008 64x

Tags: c#, asp.net, webserver

My problem is, i have the site in which .CSV file is uploaded and then read on the server.

But my server is not reading this file instead it throws me the error

> The 'Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0' provider
>   is not registered on the local
>   machine.

But it runs fine when i debug from local PC. I tried to install many drivers on my server as specified over here :-

[The 'Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0' provider is not registered on the local machine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1156146/the-microsoft-jet-oledb-4-0-provider-is-not-registered-on-the-local-machine)

[The 'Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0' provider is not registered on the local machine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1735392/the-microsoft-jet-oledb-4-0-provider-is-not-registered-on-the-local-machine)

and many more threads but still i m there.

Please help me if any one can!!!

Thanks

BHAVIK GOYAL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to enable the application pool in iis for 32bit applications.

Update:
If you only want to read CSV files, I can advise you to use a CSV reader instead of Jet because it is much faster (have a look at http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/CsvReader.aspx)

Comment: how to do that can you please help me?

Comment: Have a look [here]http://darrell.mozingo.net/2009/01/17/running-iis-7-in-32-bit-mode/

Comment: i cannot use CSV reader as the project is already been completed and deployed since last 2 years this problem has occured during the transfer of project to new server.

Comment: Thanks Pleun the link you have posted http://darrell.mozingo.net/2009/01/17/running-iis-7-in-32-bit-mode/ helps me a lot.